# in c++ - two ifndef structures in an h file leading to error c2955 use of class template requires template argument list

Tags: c++

I'm compiling two files meant to construct and test a templated stack class. The .h file contains two ifndef structures, one for a node struct and one for the stack class. the separate node and stack ifndefs are a requirement of the assignment, as worded:

> Name your class Stack, and write its specification and function
>   templates in a file named Stack.h. Use either a dynamic array or a
>   linked list to implement the class, and be sure to include dynamic
>   memory management. If you use a linked list, use Node as the node
>   struct name, and include it in Stack.h, making sure to enclose it in
>   its own #ifndef NODE / #endif container -- that will prevent compiler
>   problems when you write a queue template later.

The problem I'm having, or at least, among the problems I am having, is that when I go to compile, I'm getting "error c2955: 'stack' : use of class tempate requires template argument list" (there may be other errors but this is the main one i feel i need to resolve before I can move forward). It seems like a problem between the two ifndefs? I'd appreciate any help anyone can give me with this.

Stack.h

```
#ifndef Node
#define Node

template <class DataType>
struct Node
{
  DataType data;
  Node<DataType>* next;
};

#endif




#ifndef Stack_h
#define Stack_h

template <class DataType>
class Stack
{  
  private:
    Node<DataType>* start;
    Node<DataType>* end;


  public:
    // constructors (inline)
    Stack()
    :start(0)
    {

    }

    // getters (inline)
    bool isEmpty() const
    {
      return 0 == start;
    } // getter

    // setters
    /* push  */  void Stack<DataType>::push(const DataType& parameter);
    /* peek  */  bool Stack<DataType>::peek(DataType& parameter) const;
    /* pop   */  bool Stack<DataType>::pop(DataType& parameter);
    /* empty */  void Stack<DataType>::makeEmpty(  );




};

template <class DataType>
void Stack<DataType>::push(const DataType& parameter)
{
  Node<DataType>* node = new Node<DataType>;
  node->data = parameter;
  node->next = start;
  start = node;
}

template <class DataType>
bool Stack<DataType>::peek(DataType& parameter) const
{
  if (0 == start) return false; // failed
  parameter = start->data;
  return true; // success
}

template <class DataType>
bool Stack<DataType>::pop(DataType& parameter)
{
  if (0 == start) return false; // failed
  parameter = start->data;
  Node<DataType>* p = start->next;
  delete start;
  start = p;
  return true; // success
}

template <class DataType>
void Stack<DataType>::makeEmpty()
{
  Node<DataType>* p;
  while (start) 
  { 
    p = start->next; 
    delete start; 
    start = p;
  }
}


#endif
```

StackDriver.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "Stack.h"
#include "Stack.h" // testing ifndef


int main()
{


  cout << "Testing: creating a new int stack, adding one data value to it, then retrieving (via peep) that data" << endl << endl;

  cout << "Data to be added - 100, same data should be returned" << endl << endl;

  Stack aStack<int>;

  aStack.push( 100 );

  int dataReturn;

  aStack.peek( dataReturn );

  cout << "returned data is " << dataReturn << endl << endl;



}
```

Comment: It is not `Stack aStack<int>;` but `Stack<int> aStack;`.

Comment: This was actually the solution. Kind of blown away that this was the case but if you'd care to post this as an answer i'd be happy to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> use of class tempate requires template argument list

indicates that you actually attempted to use your class without specializing it :

`Stack aStack<int>;` has to be `Stack<int> aStack;` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation btw, that makes a lot more sense now. I guess I was fixated on the two #ifndef bits because I'm unfamiliar with that and expected it to go wrong, I really, REALLY should have been checking the more mundane errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem:

```
#define Node

template <class DataType>
struct Node
{
```

The first line makes a token replacement of `Node` being replaced by nothing.

So when the compiler gets to your later code it just sees:

```
template <class DataType>
struct
{
```

which doesn't do what you want, and leads to your errors.

To fix this, use include guards properly. You only use one guard per header file. The purpose of the guard is so that the compiler knows to not read that header file if it has already read it.

I'd also recommend using a name in all upper-case so that there is no chance of a collision between the include guards and valid tokens in your file.  The header file should look like:

```
// (First line of header)
#ifndef H_STACK
#define H_STACK

// all code goes here

#endif   // H_STACK
// (last line of header)
```

Comment: The requirements of the assignment specify using two separate include guards though, one for the class and one for the struct, and that they both be in the same .h file

Comment: Well, that's got to rank as one of the weirdest ever of these bogus assignment constraints.  Pick a name for your guard that doesn't clash with anything.